# No column in SQL database in android

Tags: android, sql

I created a SQL database and wanted to check if a row existed or not but I am getting an error saying that a column does not exist. I am trying to find the row by the current month's name.
can someone please tell me what is it that I am doing wrong.
Here is the code below:

DatabaseHelper1:

```
package com.carrot.wallet.Database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseHelper1 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int version = 1;
    private static final String name = "YEAR_DETAILS";
    private static final String COL0 = "ID";
    private static final String COL1 = "MONTH_YEAR";
    private static final String COL2 = "SPENT";
    private static final String COL3 = "REMAINING";
    private static final String TAG = "Database Helper 1";

    public DatabaseHelper1(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, name, null, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(TAG , "Database 1 is being created");
        String create_table = "CREATE TABLE "+name+"("+
                COL0+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                COL1+" TEXT, "+
                COL2+ "DOUBLE, "+
                COL3+" DOUBLE);";
        db.execSQL(create_table);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+name);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+name);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private boolean createMonth(String month){
        Log.d(TAG , "month row is being created");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1 , month);
        contentValues.put(COL2 , 0.0);
        contentValues.put(COL3 , 0.0);
        long result = db.insert(name,null , contentValues);
        return result != -1;
    }

    public boolean spentChange(String month , Double newAmount){
        Log.d(TAG , "spent amount is being changed");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL2 , newAmount);
        long result = db.update(name, values , "MONTH_YEAR = ?", new String[]{month});
        return  result != -1;
    }

    public boolean remainingChange(String month , Double newAmount){
        Log.d(TAG , "Remaining amount is being changed");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues =new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL3 , newAmount);
        long result = db.update(name , contentValues , "MONTH_YEAR = ?" , new String[]{month});
        return result != -1;
    }


     public void checkExistance(String month){
        Log.d(TAG , "Checking if month already exits");
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cur =  database.query(name , null , "MONTH_YEAR= ?" , new String[]{month} , null , null , null);
        if(cur == null) {
            boolean b = createMonth(month);
            if(b)
                Log.d(TAG , "checkExistance: failed to create month");
            else
                Log.d(TAG, "checkExistance: month created successfully");
        }
    }

    public Cursor getdata(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM YEAR_DEATAILS;";
        return db.rawQuery(query , null);
    }

}
```

HomeFragment:::

```
package com.carrot.wallet.ui;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;

import com.carrot.wallet.AddTransaction;


import com.carrot.wallet.Database.DatabaseHelper1;
import com.carrot.wallet.R;
import com.carrot.wallet.viewPager.CardAdapter;
import com.carrot.wallet.viewPager.CardDetails;
import com.carrot.wallet.viewPager.ZoomOutPageTransformer;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private ArrayList<CardDetails> cardDetailList;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final FloatingActionButton addTransaction = root.findViewById(R.id.add_transaction_button);
        ViewPager viewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        populateArrayList();
        pagerAdapter = new CardAdapter(getFragmentManager() , cardDetailList);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());


        addTransaction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity() , AddTransaction.class));
            }
        });



        return root;
    }

    private void populateArrayList(){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        String month_year =  month+"-"+year;

        DatabaseHelper1 databaseHelper1 = new DatabaseHelper1(getContext());
        databaseHelper1.checkExistance(month_year);
        Cursor data = databaseHelper1.getdata();
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            CardDetails cardDetails = new CardDetails(data.getString(1) , data.getDouble(2) , data.getDouble(3));
            cardDetailList.add(cardDetails);

        }

    }

}
```

Error:

```
2020-05-28 12:34:44.844 16406-16406/com.carrot.wallet D/Database Helper 1: Checking if month already exits
2020-05-28 12:34:44.846 16406-16406/com.carrot.wallet E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: MONTH_YEAR
2020-05-28 12:34:44.847 16406-16406/com.carrot.wallet D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-05-28 12:34:44.848 16406-16406/com.carrot.wallet E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.carrot.wallet, PID: 16406
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: MONTH_YEAR (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM YEAR_DETAILS WHERE MONTH_YEAR = ?
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:986)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:593)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1305)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1176)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1344)
        at com.carrot.wallet.Database.DatabaseHelper1.checkExistance(DatabaseHelper1.java:82)
        at com.carrot.wallet.ui.HomeFragment.populateArrayList(HomeFragment.java:70)
        at com.carrot.wallet.ui.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:45)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2722)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1188)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1514)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7843)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2122)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7695)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-05-28 12:34:44.848 16406-16406/com.carrot.wallet E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
2020-05-28 12:34:46.545 16406-16423/com.carrot.wallet W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have spelling error SELECT * FROM YEAR DEATAILS

```
public Cursor getdata(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM YEAR_DEATAILS;";
    return db.rawQuery(query , null);
}
```

also you should add spacing before =

```
MONTH_YEAR= ?
```

and I suggest you switch to Room library, it's less error prone